# Large space under text above HR in conky

Tags: conky

I have this simple `.conkyrc` config:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 255
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

double_buffer yes

use_xft yes
xftfont Sans Regular:size=70

update_interval 1

alignment middle_middle

TEXT
${alignc}Test
${hr 2}
```

which renders this.

[image]

There is a large amount of space between the large text and the horizontal rule. No where in the conky config can I see how this is being introduced, so how can it be removed?

Comment: You mean, you want to reduce the gap between the text and the horizontal line?

Comment: @Thushi Yes. The gap between the bottom of the text and the HR shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I modified your code.try this

```
       own_window yes
       own_window_type conky
       own_window_argb_visual yes
       own_window_argb_value 255
       own_window_transparent yes
       own_window_hints undecorate,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

       double_buffer yes

       use_xft yes
       xftfont Sans Regular:size=70

       #update_interval 1

       alignment middle_middle
       TEXT
       Test${voffset -60}
       ${hr 2}
```

You can adjust the voffset value according to your requirements.

Comment: This obviously works, but just seems a bit hacky. I'll accept though.

Comment: It's not an hack.You can adjust the values for `voffset`.Here I just wanted to introduce you to the `voffset`. What else are you expecting?